# Max character word from array using linq .Net

Tags: .net, arrays, linq

hey guys,
i have an array which contains some elements, now i want to check which is the largest element in the array, so what could be the query in Linq...

Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] myArray = { "a", "b", "four" };
string longest = myArray.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

...and "longest" will be equal to "four".

First, use OrderByDescending to sort the array. The result is an IEnumerable of the original strings but in the correct order (in this case descending by length). Then, using the now order IEnumerable (really an IOrderedEnumerable), take the first item - which is the longest.

Note: I use "FirstOrDefault" as good practice. You could have just used "First" here. If you are unsure whether or not your result will be null, you should use FirstOrDefault which will return the first element if it exists, otherwise it will return the default value of that Type. For a string it would return null, for a bool it would return false, for an int it would return 0, etc. In this case it is 100% safe to just use "First" instead since you know your string array is not null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your resolution was awesome, but i didnt got the concept, why you made the array OrderByDescending and then FirstOrDefault(), what does this means, can you please clear this concept, thanks for your help.

Comment: i have a gridview which i have binded through Linq, i want to know is that possible to select all the columns in one go, as we do in sql select *, is there something * concept in LINQ...

Comment: You should post that as a new question with more detail, that way you can get more people than just me looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just use Max if you are lazy like me and prefer to keep typing to a minimum. :)

```
string longest = myArray.Max();
```